# Laravel, what's the best practice to define Raw queries?

Tags: mysql, laravel, configuration

I'm crafting a Laravel App  that will perform data synchronization from DB to DB. Using MySQL.

I have set up a set of SQL raw statements that will perform some data extraction across tables and using MySQL functions.

I don't have then a 1:1 relationship in order to relate Model to table (Common Eloquent approach)

What's the suggested approach to have things set up in a clean manner?

Store SQL statements as strings in a config file?

Issue virtual model Classes having the raw query inside as class constant?

Any best practice approach in Laravel flavour?

Comment: You should avoid using, raw queries, instead you should use eloquent/query builder to build your queries. Laravel Eloquent provides many methods to build the queries into many db languages!

Comment: "I don't have then a 1:1 relationship in order to relate Model to table" Where did that came from?

Comment: $query->havingRaw('HERE YOU CAN ADD A RAW STATEMENT ON THE MODEL'). Otherwise Whats your reason for using 100% raw statements when yon chain raw statements to a modal/class?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi I'm not talking about many db languages but specifically about MySQL. IMHO Eloquent ORM fails and have memory leaks on complex queries. And also it's is not possible to reproduce SQL queries using functions or subqueries. That's the reason behind , every ORM provides a raw query functionality.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi Yes I realise that sentence is a bit confusing. I'm referring to the fact that I can't map a single model class to a sigle table. Since my queries join multiple tables

Comment: @Birdy I'm not asking hoe to perform a raw query. I know that. I'm asking where would I place these statement in the code. To have them listed in one place (as if they are configurations of my app)